# gdb shows During startup program exited normally. in WSL (Bash on Windows, Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL(Bash on Windows = Windows Subsystem for Linux).
I wrote a simple code, a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it.

```
$ gcc -g -o a.exe a.c
$
```

It worked well.

```
$ ./a.exe 
Hello
$
```

And, I tried to execute a.exe in gdb. However, I got "During startup program exited normally."

```
$ gdb ./a.exe
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.exe...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/softgear/a.exe 
During startup program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

How can I use gdb in WSL? Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is already reported and fixed [WSL bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2870).

As a workaround you can `set disable-randomization off` before debugging, see https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2870#issuecomment-359664608. Or update WSL to a latest version.

Comment: The workaround works. ( I added `set disable-randomization off` into /etc/gdb/gdbinit file ).